# C++ std::function to take functions with sub class parameter

Tags: c++, function, polymorphism, subclass, std-function

[Update] Reason for this question:
There are many existing lambdas defined as `[](const ChildType1& child)`, all in a big registry. We want to register new lambdas like `[](const ChildType2& child)` in the same registry. If we define the function wrapper using `Parent`, for the many existing lambdas we need to change them to `[](const Parent& someone)`, and inside downcast from `Parent` to `ChildType1`.

---

If I have a function wrapper as `std::function<void(const Parent&)>`, is there any way to allow it take a function with `Parent` subclass as parameter, e.g., `[](const Child& child){...}`, where `Child` is a subclass of `Parent`.

Something below does not compile. Online IDE [link](https://onlinegdb.com/fF4Zv2xSb).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Parent {
    public:
        virtual void say() const {
            std::cout<<"I am parent"<<"\n";
        }
};

class Child: public Parent {
    public:
        void say() const {
            std::cout<<"I am child"<<"\n";
        }
};

typedef std::function<void(const Parent&)> Wrapper;

int main() {
    Wrapper func=[](const Child& child){  // of course works if Child->Parent
      child.say();
    };
    
    Child c;
    func(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No there is no way, this is logically broken as one could pass in a `Parent` to a function which expects a `Child`.

Comment: No, that's the wrong kind of variance. See covariance and contravariance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to make it `Wrapper func=[](const Parent& child) { .. };`? You could still call it with a `Child` (and its `say()` function would be called).

Comment: The reason is that there are many existing lambdas defined as `[](const ChildType1& child)`, all in a big registry. We want to register new lambdas like `[](const ChildType2& child)` in the same registry. If we define the function wrapper using `Parent`, in the many existing lambdas we need to do downcasting from `Parent` to `ChildType1`.

Comment: @Robert I don't see why you would need to downcast here. You have polymorphism so you could just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why isn't this allowed ?

This is not allowed by the language because it might lead to inconsistencies.

With your definition of `Wrapper`, the following code should be legitimate:

```
Wrapper f; 
Parent x; 
... // Initialize f with a legitimate function dealing Parent 
f(x);
```

Now imagine two classes:

```
class Child1: public Parent {
    public:
        void say() const {
            std::cout<<"I am child1"<<"\n";
        }
        virtual void tell() const {
            std::cout<<"This is specific to child1"<<"\n";
        }
};
class Child2: public Parent {
    public:
        void say() const {
            std::cout<<"I am child2"<<"\n";
        }
};
```

The following code would also be valid, since `Child1` and `Child2` derive from `Parent`:

```
Child1 y; 
Child2 z; 
f(y);   
f(z);
```

If you were allowed to assign a function with a child argument instead of a parent argument for your wrapper,  you could as well do something like:

```
Wrapper f=[](const Child1& child){  // if this is legitimate
  child.tell();                     //   then this would be legitimate
};
```

And you'll easily guess that `f(x)` and `f(z)` would not work although the type of `f` should allow it.

### Is there a work-around?

What you can do,  but this is something more risky,  is to make a wrapper function that takes a `Parent` argmument and down-casts is to a `Child`.  But I'd not recommend it unless there's no other solution and only with extra-care.

```
using Wrapper = std::function<void(const Parent&)>;

int main() {
    Wrapper func=[](const Parent& parent){
      auto child=dynamic_cast<const Child*>(&parent);  
      if (child)
        child->say();
      else std::cout<<"OUCH!!! I need a child"<<std::endl; 
    };
    
    Parent x; 
    Child c;
    func(c);
    func(x); 
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/RFq5sUmWd)